# Show red border when input is empty or invalid email format using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an email input and I want if the field is empty and the user clicks inside the input and then outside shows a red border and an error message until the user has enter anything in the input. I have done this using jQuery and it works 100%. Here is the code in sign_in.php:

```
<form action="sign_in.php" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email_3" id="email_3" class="form-control form-control-lg validate"
    value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email_3'])){ echo $_POST['email_3'];}?>" style="width:455px; background-color:#EEEEEE;">
    <div class="error_2" style="font-size: 14.5px;">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).on('blur','.validate',function(){
  if(!$.trim($(this).val())){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.error_2').show()
    $(this).addClass('error_show')
    $(this).addClass('error_show_2')
  }
}).on('focus','.validate',function(){
   $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.error_2').hide()
   $(this).removeClass('error_show')
   $(this).removeClass('error_show_2')
})
</script>
```

Here is the code of main.css:

```
.validate:hover,
.validate:focus{
 border: 3px solid #EEA730;
}

.error_show_2{
  border:1px solid red !important;
}

.error_show:hover{
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #EEA730 !important;
 border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

Now also I need to add that if the email is written in an invalid format show the red border and show the message so I add this to my code:

```
<script>
$(document).on('blur','.validate',function(){
  if(!$.trim($(this).val()) || /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.error_2').show()
    $(this).addClass('error_show')
    $(this).addClass('error_show_2')
  }
}).on('focus','.validate',function(){
   $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.error_2').hide()
   $(this).removeClass('error_show')
   $(this).removeClass('error_show_2')
})
</script>
```

I mean here if the input is empty or if user has enter an invalid email format show the red border and show the message but it didn't work. How to do this?

Comment: As a counter-point: why? HTML5 can already do this for free without any kind of Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Using_built-in_form_validation so trying to do this yourself using JS/jQuery is probably putting effort where it's not needed. Just leave it to the form?

Comment: But not what I wanted especially for the styles as you can see in the code. Also, for blur and focus and the displayed message :(

Comment: If you read the link that Mike posted, you can customise the style of the built-in validation using CSS

Comment: I want to display the message under the input not a popup ... How can I do this? It says: The way this message is displayed depends on the browser. These automated messages have two drawbacks:
There is no standard way to change their look and feel with CSS.                                                          They depend on the browser locale, which means that you can have a page in one language but an error message displayed in another language. I can only change it using javascript. So, same as I do but with jQuery...